# При чём или причём?

Tags: синтаксис, предлоги, слитно-раздельно, союзы, местоимения

Что-то меня слегка переклинило. Пишу: *"Функциональный анализ тут **ни причём**"* — и не знаю, слитно или раздельно здесь пишется "причём"?

P.S. Кстати, нужен ли тут знак вопроса? Формально это ведь утверждение: я не знаю.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Сочетание НИ ПРИ ЧЁМ пишется в три слова: *...анализ тут **ни при чём.***
Постановка "?" не требуется.

Чтобы Вы лучше разобрались в правописании, напомню Вам ещё два правила. Думаю, что, прочитав их, путаться в употреблении не будете.

Сочетание ПРИ ЧЁМ употребляется в вопросительных предложениях или в сложноподчиненных предложениях при присоединении изъяснительных придаточных:
***При чём*** здесь наши отношения?
*Я спросил его* (о чём?), ***при чём*** здесь приезжие гости, если они никакого отношения к его работе не имеют (придаточное изъяснительное).

Союз ПРИЧЁМ пишется слитно, его надо отличать от сочетания предлога с местоимениями ПРИ ЧЁМ. Союз имеет присоединительное значение, синонимичен (имеет синонимы ДА И, ВМЕСТЕ С ТЕМ, К ТОМУ ЖЕ) и его легко можно заменить на союз ПРИТОМ:
*Он вернулся через два часа и получил тот же ответ, **причём*** (притом, к тому же, вместе с тем) *лакей как-то косо посмотрел на него.*

Comment: Спасибо! Особенно понравилось "притом" - легко запомнить. Буду пользоваться. 
Кстати, сочетание "при том" тоже есть ;-)

Comment: Я присоединяюсь к сказанному. Но в отноешнии "при чем"/"причем" есть о чем поговорить. Даже тут это было неоднократно. Мне сейчас ссылки искать трудно, попробуйте самостоятельно, если есть интерес.

Comment: Конечно, есть. Но спрашивали о ПРИЧЕМ?!

Comment: Поискала, нашла одну, но довольно тривиальную.

Comment: Ну знаете...
А какую?

А попробуй сам найти, но позже...Сейчас, простите, душевное состояние не позволяет сосредоточиться.

Comment: [эту](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/903/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
Не торопитесь, займитесь собой... Вопрос совершенно не срочный.

Comment: Еще мы в комментариях к какому -то вопросу обсуждали это. Вопрос был на другую тему. Поэтому поиск и не выдает результата.  К сожалению, не помню вопроса.

Comment: >займитесь собой...   
  
Та не, я не с том смысле. )))
Приступ идиосинкразии да всякую мозговую деятельность. 
Резко потеплело. Теперь буду от жары умирать. И интернет еле дышит.
Это раз
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/16310/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, изучу. Радует, что здесь все-таки есть проблема, а не просто моя безграмотность ;-)

Comment: Не за что... И я тоже жару не люблю. Хотя сейчас -то ее вроде бы еще и нет. У нас так вообще снег с дождем почти каждый день.

Answer (score 5):

В приведенном Вами предложении "при чем" - это местоимение с предлогом, а союз "причем" обычно начинает собой присоединительные конструкции ("Я люблю читать книги, причем хорошие").